# Formula - Excel Sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi I am trying to write the below in a formula but I am having some problems, I tried to a formula but is not working.

You write amount (and on which category the amount fall it will work the sum)

```
If amount is between 0.00 to 9100.00 = 0% - 0.00
If amount is between 9101.00 to 14500.00 = 15% - 1365
If amount is between 14501.00 to 19500.00 = 25% - 2815
If amount is between 19501.00 to 60000.00 = 25% - 2725
If amount is between 60001.00 and over = 35% - 8725
```

- mean minus.

Comment: Nested IF should do it, but please explain the formula a bit more. So if I have an amount of 10,000, what are you expecting as the outcome? Is it (10,000 * 0.15) - 1365 = 135? Please edit your question with more specifics on what the formula should do, with an example.

Answer (score -1):

Use CHOOSE(MATCH()):

```
=A1*CHOOSE(MATCH(A1,{0,9101,14501,19501,6001}),0,0.15,0.25,0.25,0.35)-CHOOSE(MATCH(A1,{0,9101,14501,19501,6001}),0,1365,2815,2725,8725)
```